# Can we use consistent ashfall to help reclaim or create topsoil?

Tags: environment, flora, ecology, farming

Earth has reached a point of significant desertification due to issues such as climate change, deforestation, pollution, etc. Because of this there's significant topsoil loss across the planet. What's left of humanity is desperately struggling to grow enough crops for both the world population as well as to stall total ecological collapse. As time progresses, topsoil loss is getting worse and worse due to both environmental and human factors (war, more pollution etc)

At some point ash started to fall from the sky, much in the way like it would with rain. The ashfall can vary, sometimes caking areas, other times lightly dusting place. The ashfall isn't going anywhere. It's part of the weather pattern.

**How would humanity utilize these ashfalls to help reclaim the desertified land such that they have topsoil capable of yielding crops and plant life in general?**

The answer doesn't have to yield a one and done permanent solution. If the process requires dependence on the ashfall continually to create new topsoil from desertified dirt or formerly good topsoil in a recycling like fashion, then that's fine.

Edit:
The ash alone doesn't have to be the answer alone. It just has to help or aid. If it's part of some larger process or a system of things that's just as fine. Ideally the way it would be used would be in an industrial scale.

Comment: What is the origin / composition of the Ash?

Comment: There are many things called ash. *Actual* ash, that is, what remains when you burn coal or wood, won't help much if at all. So, *what is it* that falls from the sky and is called ash in the question?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. How would they utilize the ashfall? It sounds like they have no choice but to till it in and hope for the best. If it's not useful, is it falling in low enough quantities or in a limited enough area that given the available technology it can be removed if not found to be valuable? This is a little bit like asking how would humans utilize acid rain. It's on the ground whether we like it or not....

Comment: @Gillgamesh For now the origin of the ash is just handwaved in. But you can assume that the ashfall itself is good enough to help crops grow if you were to process it like a fertilizer. As in it has the required elements needed for growing organic fauna. Think like volcanic ash roughly. Too much or unprocessed and it's bad for plants/crops/vegetation (Sulphur in high quantities I believe is a big issue for volcanic ashfall). But when processed and applied methodically to crops it's a great fertilizer.

Comment: @JBH Ashfall is global. My question is, can they use this ashfall to help reclaim topsoil that was lost due to multiple issues. For example, ash from volcanic eruptions can be collected, processed, and used as a fertilizer to help crops grow. Presumably whatever ash that falls down has some properties that lends itself to be able to be used for growing crops or soil reclamation. So, it would be something on the lines of volcanic ash compared to say just burned wood or newspaper. The former has benefits and can be used as nutrients for plants, the latter not so much.

Comment: [Wood ash has many useful applications for restoring soil](https://www.rhs.org.uk/soil-composts-mulches/wood-ash-using-in-garden). Maybe burnt plastic isn't useful, but is there a worldbuilding question here? At the moment it looks like a research qeustion that's easily answered with Google.

Comment: @JBH The worldbuilding question here would be, what large scale process would people be using ash in to help create or reclaim topsoil. Current research that I've done focuses only on using things like volcanic ash as general fertilizer for smaller scale stuff. Ideally, I'm looking for an industrial solution since a significant portion of the planet is basically a desert due to environmental issues. Lastly, applications for ash that I've researched focuses on working with already existing topsoil. This question focuses on how to use ash to help reclaim or make topsoil

Comment: That's not a worldbuilding question. Worse, since you have an unavoidable world-wide ashfall, what are people going to do? Not till it in? That's part of my concern here. It's not as if anyone has a choice. Whether or not the ash is beneficial is irrelevant to the choice they can make. Besides, most ash is beneficial. But like all additives, you need more than just ash to be successful.  If the average ashfall is a couple of meters thick the issue is entirely moot. Everything's dead. If it's a couple of centimeters, till it in and grow your crops. How much it helps depends on the soil type.

Comment: So the answer to your question is "yes, basically because the unavoidable alternative is death." Keep in mind that answering the question on behalf of the entire planet is probably too broad for the rules. Worse, all that ash falling into the oceans might make usefulness for farming irrelevant. And you can expect the planet to cool down since ash is a pretty good insulator that will keep everything pole-side of the tropics from warming up. I think you need to practice deciding what the outcome you want is - because leaving the outcome to us makes questions like this too often off-topic.

Comment: @FIRES_ICE, Wood ash can't be used to reclaim topsoil. It contains a lot of calcium carbonate (lime) which increases alkalinity, which makes it harder for plants to absorb nutrients from the soil.

Answer (score 4):

**If your ash has the right composition, you are willing to wait a bit and put in a lot of effort, this might work**

There is a precedence to what you want to do: Loess is a general term for soil that is created from sediments brought in by wind (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loess). It is very fertile and worlds food production relies on it. But Loess is such a good soil because it meets very specific requirements regarding grain size, nutrient content and pH (carbonate content). So your "ash" would have to look kind of like those sediments, which might be a stretch on the term. Historically, these sediments were comings from soils in other places (e.g. deserts), not from burning things.

This material in itself is not enough for a good soil. As @L.Dutch pointed out, soil also consists of soil microorganisms, organic carbon etc. but humans did overcome this by adding a lot of charcoal and other things to the soils (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terra_preta). Keep in mind that this requires a *huge* amount of carbon to do on a big scale. I do not know, how fast it would be possible to grow crops on this kind of "self-made" soil, but I would guess it could work within a few years. Of course, it will take much more time until it can be compared to "true" soil.

Given the effort necessary to make new soil and the problems that are caused for your plants by the constant "ash-rain", I would recommend thinking about hydroponics instead. You could still use the ashes as fertilizer for the hydroponic facilities, if it contains nutrients (e.g. nitrate, phosphate).

*edit:* The amount of ash needed for nutrients in hydroponics depends highly on assumptions. I will focus on nitrate. Lets assume we have a country with 10,000,000 inhabitants and need 5 kg biomass per person and day (this is much more than they actually eat, because not the whole plant is eadible). Biomass contains roughly 3 percent nitrogen (https://www.cropnutrition.com/nutrient-management/nitrogen), so this comes down to 6.6 Mio kg nitrate/day (1.5 Mio kg nitrogen). Assuming they do not recycle any nutrients and a nitrate content in the ash of 0.1 %, this comes down to **~7 Mio tons of ash** they have to process per day. You can change this to your liking by assuming some nutrient recycling or changing the nitrate content in the ash.

Keep in mind that most numbers I used were mostly arbitrary. The most questionable assumption is probably the complete lack of recycling of nutrients.

Comment: If hydroponics were involved, how much ash would they end up using assuming it contains nutrients? The farming would have to be large enough to feed a small country.

Answer (score 3):

Cultivable soil is more than just grounded rock.

Apart from the right granulometry, you need to have the right micro-organisms and the right organic compounds available to be able to grow something.

That's why the evolution of soil starts from pioneer organisms which can do with the scarce possibilities offered by virgin rock, slowly building up the mix for more complex life to thrive. You can't grow crops on a freshly cooled lava field!

In the same way, just having hashes (of whatever type they are) on a desert soil won't by magic turn it into fertile soil. You even risk doing things worse, because the hash might unbalance the already fragile equilibrium of that nutrient poor substrate.

Comment: Corned beef hash might work.  And also smell great.  Initially it would smell great but maybe not so much later.

Answer (score 1):

**Tholin snow**

https://www.sciencealert.com/the-red-plains-of-pluto-s-cthulhu-macula-may-not-be-what-we-thought

> When New Horizons approached Pluto in 2015, it gave us something
> wondrous: the clearest view we'd ever seen of the distant, tiny dwarf
> planet.

[image: pluto]

> In crisp images, fascinating terrain was revealed - including a broad
> swath of red sweeping around Pluto's equator: a non-icy landscape on
> an otherwise remarkably icy body.
>
> Analysis suggested that the reddish plain was produced by molecules
> known as tholins, organic compounds that form in the atmosphere when
> ultraviolet or cosmic radiation cooks compounds that contain carbon,
> such as methane or carbon dioxide, that then rain down onto the
> surface. ....
>
> Tholins aren't the only available explanation for Pluto's red patches
> of which the Cthulhu Macula is the largest - but it did seem to be the best fit. New Horizons detected a haze in the dwarf planet's
> atmosphere, including methane, nitrogen, and carbon dioxide.

> When irradiated, these compounds should turn russet and fall down to
> the surface, staining it a muddy red. Tholins are common in the outer
> Solar System, particularly on icy bodies, so it only makes sense,
> right?

Cthulhu Macula!  It is so awesome that Lovecraft's works are in the public domain!

The "ash" that rains on your world is not wood ash from wildfires or mineral ash from volcanic eruptions.  It is reduced carbon and nitrogen compounds from the immense stores of the planetary disk, gently toasted by the star and agglomerated into reddish microparticles.

This stuff it is rich in microbe food (reduced carbon) and reduced nitrogen that microbes and plants need to make proteins.  It is as good as yard waste mulch,  The tholin snow aka "ash" combined with the depleted mineral soil that remains on your world's surface very much makes good soil.

I am a little concerned that tholins do not contain much phosphorus which is an essential mineral nutrient.  That is getting a ways into the weeds, though.